# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

у меня возникла такая ошибка когда я пытаюсь записать данные в бд

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (period, email, ordername, room) values ('2020-09-30', 'andriyk', 'r', 2)' at line 1
```

Бд:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ентити:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order")
public class Order {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "order_id")
private int order_id;
@Column(name = "ordername")
private String ordername;
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;
@Column(name = "period")
private Date date;
@Column(name = "room")
private int room;

public Order() {

}

public Order(int order_id, String ordername, String email, Date date, int room) {
    this.order_id = order_id;
    this.ordername = ordername;
    this.email = email;
    this.date = date;
    this.room = room;
}


public int getOrder_id() {
    return order_id;
}

public void setOrder_id(int order_id) {
    this.order_id = order_id;
}

public String getOrdername() {
    return ordername;
}

public void setOrdername(String ordername) {
    this.ordername = ordername;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public int getRoom() {
    return room;
}

public void setRoom(int room) {
    this.room = room;
}
```

}

Дао:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void addOrder(Order order) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(order);
}
```

Hibernate properties:

```
private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.search.default.directory_provider",
            "org.hibernate.search.store.impl.FSDirectoryProvider");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty(
            "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty(
            "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

    return hibernateProperties;
}
```

Comment: ORDER - зарезервированное слово. [Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-O). Кому пришло в голову так назвать таблицу?

Comment: @Akina сорян, я сам новачок, не знал.